# 32-bit software accessing files from system32 folder instead of syswow64 folder in Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: 32bit-64bit, dll

I installed a 32-bit application on Windows 10 64-bit and it installed dll files in the **syswow64** folder, but while running, it accesses files from **system32** folder instead of the **syswow64** folder.

The application is not running properly.

I tried reinstalling and compatibility check but it does not work.

Comment: What software and version? What lead you to the conclusion that this is the problem? Which windows edition & version? Which of the diagnostic steps of related questions have you already attempted, with what results?

Answer (score 2):

As @RohitGupta mentions, installing the 32-bit DLLs in SysWow64 is standard procedure, but for your app to be using the ones in System32 is wrong. Normally Windows will make a local directory substitution when it finds that it is running a 32-bit application, but in this case apparently it is failing to do that. The most common reason in my experience for that to happen is if the base application is CPU-agnostic, running as managed code in the .Net environment for instance. Because the application does not have a bit width requirement, it is run with the 64-bit version of the framework for efficiency, and so will try to link with the 64-bit DLLs. You need to contact the manufacturer of the application and confirm whether it is using the .Net framework, or some similar virtualization scheme, and get a version of the application that is set to use the 32-bit DLLs - the .Net framework has a bit flag that can be set in the application header to restrict it to using 32-bit DLLs and COM objects.

Edit: For the .Net framework, the tool that sets the necessary flag bit is called `corflags.exe` and should be available with any of the Windows .Net developer packages from Microsoft. Syntax is `corflags <executablename> /32bit+`

Comment: Thank you tsc_chazz for details information .but the manufacturer of the application is not providing his service now. So can you help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: About all I can suggest is what I had above - fetch the current Visual Studio package from Microsoft (there is a free tier), or try to find just corflags.exe. Then run `corflags <executable.exe> /32bit+` to try to set that flag bit. Either it will work, and you'll be set; or it won't, and we'll need more information to find out what will make it work.

Comment: Thank you.I will Try and let you know .

Comment: HI tsc_chazz i Run  run corflags <executable.exe> /32bit+ and get this error.

corflags : error CF008 : The specified file does not have a valid managed header

Please Guide me.

Comment: You haven't given us the name of the program you're having trouble with. I was expecting that you would replace `<executable.exe>` with the actual program you're trying to run; did you do that? And if so, please say what the program is you need to run, so we can research what would actually work.

Comment: yes i replaced it with my exe name  corflags.exe "c:\programfile.........\myexename.exe" /32bit+. and software is not available online bz its developed by some local vendor. but if you say i can send you exe on mail.

Comment: No promises, but... I've created a temporary email address for myself. Zip up the executable and send it to my username at manna dot bc dot ca and I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: Thank you tsc_chazz .I sended.

Comment: Got it. This program does use a virtual machine, but it is ancient - Visual Basic 6.0. Let me see what I can find.

Comment: Yes this program developed in Visual Basic 6.and hope you will give the solution.

Comment: Seem No body have solution here.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to work on it yet; needed to create a sacrificial Win10 machine, as I have no assurance this program is safe, and now have to find a VB6 install disk. But I do have to ask: what exactly is the error message you're getting? On my first attempt I got a "non-instantiated class" error because the VB6 VM DLL was not available.

Comment: Thanks for your Response tsc_chazz. Actualy after installation of this software most of the functionality are fine but one function  in which this exe open a look-up ( active-x dll )which loads some data from database and after selecting a data on that lookup it not return values to exe. If you want i can give you the access of my vm to you.

Comment: It is very annoying to find out that the problem you're attempting to solve is not, in fact, the problem that needs solving. That actually is the main thing that anx, in the comment to your initial post, was trying to avoid. Could have reached this point a lot sooner if you had analysed your problem a bit better. Oh, well... I've reactivated that email account; this will only appear on your vm so I suppose you'd better send me credentials.

Comment: Hi,I mailed you .Please check

Answer (score 1):

Despite it looking weird, on Windows 64, the 64 bit files are in **system32** (for compatibility).  And 32 bit files are in **syswow64**.

Here is an example.  Have a look at Processor and Flags properties.

[image]